# Can I put a filepath and then the file name/extension in place of this?

Tags: python, download, urllib2, filepath, urllib

I am making a simple application in Python that downloads a file from a website. This application has to put said file in a specific location.

```
      import urllib
      urllib.urlretrieve ("http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3", "mp3.mp3")
```

In the above code, which I got from an answer on the question, [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python), I am guessing that "mp3.mp3" is the file that will be stored locally after it is downloaded from the URL. That brings me to my next question: can I put a filepath and then the file name/extension in place of "mp3.mp3"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how it works. The documentation for urllib can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of great information [here](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html), but in addition:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.google.com', 'dir\\to\\wherever')
```